# Point subdomain to specific page of my site - Wordpress & Godaddy

Tags: wordpress

I am planning to develop a website in wordpress

I would like to point a subdomain shop.my-domain.com to an specific page of my domain site: my-domain.com/shop (of course I dont want to redirect them)

How can I do this?

I am using GoDaddy for hosting

Answer (score 0):

For pointing your domain to particular subdomain in GoDaddy hosing you need to take support of Godaddy. You need to say them to point your domain to particular subdomain to your domain.